# Regex UserId from Github link

Tags: python, regex

I need to get the UserID from a github link

Example:

```
https://github.com/myName/blabla/ or 
https://github.com/myName/
https://github.com/myName
```

output should be `myName`.

My code:

```
(\/github.com\/)\/(.*?)(\/)?
```

Comment: That doesn't look like python code.

Answer (score 1):

You've got an extra slash in the middle, and you don't need the slash at the end, just grab characters that aren't slashes for the username:

```
/github\.com/([^/]+)
```

Your match will be in group 1.

Interactive demo: https://regex101.com/r/vEOksV/2

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

text = 'https://github.com/testName/'

try:
    found = re.search('github\.com\/(.+?)\/', text).group(1)
except AttributeError:
    # pattern not found
    found = '' # apply your error handling

# found: testName
```

Interactive IDE with this example: https://onlinegdb.com/ry1w1dSB8

Comment: This is incorrect - it doesn't match all the OP's test cases.

Comment: OP modified the test cases after my answering of the question. The only modification is to make the last slash optional in the regular expression.

Comment: They did modify the test cases (before you answered the question), but the failing test case is in the original: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/60624780/1